# Apply impulse not working

Tags: objective-c, vector, sprite-kit

I'm using the following code to have a ball be falling and whenever I tap it it should hop back up, hence the apply impulse in my touchesBegan method. However when I run this code the ball begins to fall but when I tap on it, it juste keeps falling. What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */
[ball.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 8)];
}

-(void) addBall
{
SKShapeNode *ball;
ball = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:30];
ball.strokeColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:114.0f/255.0f green:84.0f/255.0f blue:123.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
ball.fillColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:114.0f/255.0f green:84.0f/255.0f blue:123.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
ball.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2,self.size.height/2);

//add physics body
ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:30];


[self addChild:ball];
}

-(void)didMoveToView: (SKView *)view
{
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:113.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:248.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
//add phsyics body to the scene
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];

//change gravity
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -6);



[self addBall];
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your impulse value is very low. Increase it or reduce gravity, try this code works.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */
for (SKSpriteNode *node in self.children) {
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"ball"])
        [node.physicsBody applyImpulse:
         CGVectorMake(0, 100)];
         NSLog(@"tapped ball");
}
}

-(void)didMoveToView: (SKView *)view
{
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:113.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:248.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
//add phsyics body to the scene
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];

//change gravity
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -6);



[self addBall];
}

-(void) addBall {
    ball = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:30];
    ball.fillColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:225.0f/255.0f green:76.0f/255.0f blue:76.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    ball.strokeColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:225.0f/255.0f green:76.0f/255.0f blue:76.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    ball.position = CGPointMake(self.size.height/2, self.size.width/2);
    ball.name = @"ball";
    ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:30];

    [self addChild:ball];
}
```

Comment: I put an NSLog statement to see if it's registering the tap at all and it is but it's just not applying that impulse.

Comment: I tested it works. Did you add name to your ball? like this ball.name = @"ball";

Comment: Still not working I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I edited my code in with your answer if you could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to use to apply impulse.

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

// if ball is tapped apply impulse
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"ball"]) {
    [node.physicsBody applyImpulse:
     CGVectorMake(0, 80)];

    NSLog(@"ball pressed");
}
}


-(void) addBall
{
SKShapeNode *ball;
ball = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:30];
ball.strokeColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:114.0f/255.0f green:84.0f/255.0f blue:123.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
ball.fillColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:114.0f/255.0f green:84.0f/255.0f blue:123.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
ball.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2,self.size.height/2);
ball.name = @"ball";
//add physics body
ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:30];

[self addChild:ball];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what makes your code the solution?  e.g.  What was the issue in the original code and what you changed to make it work correctly. Code only answer are considered low quality and sometimes are closed.

Comment: The code in the first part of the question is all correct except I wasn't assigning any name to my ball node. In the solution I added "ball.name = @"ball";" to the addBall method. I did this so my code in the didBeginContact method would recognize the name of what I'm tapping as being the ball so It can react properly.

Answer (score -1):

The `ball` you create and add a physics body to in `addBall` is not the same one you're applying an impulse to in `touchesBegan`. In `addBall` it's a local variable. Perhaps you mean to make it a property? Then refer to it as `self.ball` in both places.

Comment: Well Im putting this above the @implementation line: SKShapeNode *ball; So that should work just as well right?